# DataStudio ::: Count_Distinct Calculation based on two values

Tags: sql, looker-studio

I have a data set with two values. The first being User ID, the second being Type.

I previously had a count_distinct on the user ID. However, if a user changes their Type, the metrics we have to show 'Type' of user shows two instances of that once unique user.

I would like some SQL which basically states if the User ID and Type Match, then count that as a unique user. If either one of those change, count that also as a unique user. So that..

```
1) Jane Doe - Support User
2) Jane Doe - Employee User
3) John Smith - Support User
```

This would show as 3 unique users, rather than 2 based on a count_unique on just the User ID.

Comment: Please show us what your data looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to accomplish this is with a [calculated field](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6299685?hl=en) that looks something like the following:

```
COUNT_DISTINCT(CONCAT(USER_ID, ' - ', TYPE))
```

You might need to replace `USER_ID` and `TYPE` with your field names.